# Should have a non-void return value to indicate whether or not an error occurred

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi every1 below is my code in which I'm getting memory leaks.
I'm really new to handling memory leak so please be kind to me even if its a simple bug.

```
-(void) parseActivityData:(NSMutableData*) data parseError:(NSError **)error
{
    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [parser parse];
    NSError *parseError = [parser parserError];
    if (parseError && error) {
        *error = parseError;
    }
    [*error retain];

    [parser release];   
}
```

for this code I'm getting this memory leak issues one is "Method accepting NSError should have a non-void return value to indicate whether or not an error occurred" and the other is DeDereference of null pointer(loaded from variable 'error').
Thanks

Comment: Plz consider the code from -(void) parseActivityData:(NSMutableData*) data parseError:(NSError **)error{

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do what's requested. Return a BOOL instead of void that is set to NO when you actually use the error param. Also do not `[*error retain];`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
-(BOOL) parseActivityData:(NSMutableData*) data parseError:(NSError **)error
{
    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    BOOL success = [parser parse];
    // only assign error if parser FAILED
    if(success == NO)
    {
        // error should be autoreleased... no need to retain
        *error = [parser parserError];

        // if the above line doesn't work (if error also releases
        // when you release the parser object), then take out the above
        // line of code and uncomment this line below:
        // 
        // *error = [[parser parserError copy];
        //
        // the above line makes a retained copy of the error, which
        // you must release in the caller.  
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't fix the error "Method accepting NSError should have a non-void return value".